# Relative vibration damping relating to viscous damping

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I would like to understand better the information provided by a flexible coupling manufacturer (see [this document](https://www.vulkan.com/en-us/drivetech/Documents/DriveTech-Catalogues/Highly-flexible-couplings-drivetech.pdf), page 42), and how it relates to the viscous damping . In specific, the manufacturer provides the 'Relative Torsional Vibration Damping' which is a unitless number defined as follows:

"Relative Torsional Vibration Damping $\Psi$: The relative damping $\Psi_{\text{nominal}}$ is the ratio of the damping energy, converted into heat during a vibration cycle, to the flexible strain energy."

However, I struggle to understand how this $\Psi$ relates to the viscous damping coefficient $C$ which comes in the form of $T=C\dot{x}$ (where $T$ is the torque due to damping and $\dot{x}$ is the rotational speed). I am tempted to assume that $\Psi$ as defined there is equivalent to the well-known damping ratio $\zeta$, however I am not too sure. Any clarification/insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These "rubber damper" materials do *not* behave like viscous dampers with a constant coefficient $T = C\dot x$. For a given amplitude $x$, they dissipate a constant amount of energy in each vibration cycle, independent of the frequency.

If you want to include them in the usual equations for steady-state forced response, you model them as a complex *stiffness* term, not as a damping term, i.e. $$-M\omega^2 x(\omega) + K(1 + i \eta)x(\omega) = F(\omega)$$ where $\eta$ is the (constant) damping coefficient.

Google for "hysteretic damping" or "structural damping" for more details of the theory if you haven't seen this before.

Maybe the specification document gives you the value of $\eta$ somewhere. (I'm not going to search though 200+ pages of multi-lingual text to try and find it for you!)

Otherwise, work out the loss of energy in one cycle and compare it with the total energy in the system.

Comment: I have throught about this myself. Unfortunately no other damping-related information is provided, and the definition of hysteretic damping seems to be far from the one they provide for the 'Relative damping coefficient' (correct me if I am wrong).